# How to join between two tables when there's another that you're not using in the middle?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am looking to create a select statement. My problem is I don't know where to start. I am looking to concatenate first and last name from Field table. Then I want to get project number and the project name from the Project table. The relationship is (Field 1:N Work N:1 Project). I don't know how to do a join with the Work table in the middle.

```
CREATE TABLE project (
    proNumber                SMALLINT not null ,
    proName                  VARCHAR(25), 
    proLocation              VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    proDeptNumber           SMALLINT,
constraint   pkProj   primary key(proNumber)
);

CREATE TABLE Field (
    SSN                   CHAR(9) ,
    LastName             VARCHAR(25),
    FirstName            VARCHAR(25),
    MiddleName           VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    Address               VARCHAR(50) NULL,
    City                  VARCHAR(25) NULL,
    State                 CHAR(2) NULL,
    Zip                   CHAR(9) NULL,
    DateOfBirth         DATETIME NULL,
    Salary                FLOAT(8,2) not null,  
    ParkingSpace         INT,
    Gender                CHAR(1) NULL,
    DptNumber            SMALLINT,
    SuperID              CHAR(9),
constraint   pkField  PRIMARY KEY(ssn)
);

CREATE Work (
    workEmpSSN              CHAR(9) not null,
    workProNumber           SMALLINT not null,
    workHours                DECIMAL(5,1) NULL,
    workHoursPlanned        DECIMAL(5,1) NULL,
constraint  pkAssign   PRIMARY KEY (workEmpSSN, workProNumber)
);
```

Comment: Can you post your schema so we can determine how the tables are related?

Answer (score 2):

Next time, you should provide more information, like a minimal schema.
I suppose it looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE field (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  first_name VARCHAR(10),
  last_name VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT INTO field (first_name, last_name)
VALUES ('fn1', 'ln1'), ('fn2', 'ln2');

CREATE TABLE project (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  work_id INT
);

INSERT INTO project (name, work_id)
VALUES ('P1', 1), ('P2', 1), ('P3', 3), ('P4', 2), ('P5', 1);

CREATE TABLE work (
  project_id INT,
  field_id INT,
  FOREIGN KEY (project_id) REFERENCES project(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (field_id) REFERENCES field(id)
);

INSERT INTO work (project_id, field_id) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 1), (3, 2);
```

You could simply use two `JOIN`, like this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(field.first_name, ' ', field.last_name) AS field_name, project.name AS project_name, project.id AS project_number
FROM work
JOIN field ON field.id = work.field_id
JOIN project ON project.id = work.project_id
ORDER BY project_number;
```

1. I am using `CONCAT` to concatenate two fields from your query (to get an other one, which I call `field_name`).
2. I am using two `JOIN` with their respective `ON` clause.

See [it live on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d185/1/0).

**EDIT:** Totally misunderstand your original question, sorry. [This](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2d185/1) should be fine!

Comment: I am totally confused this is returning a empty set. I guess it was left out that I need information from the assignment table. The field table has the first name and last name.The work table has work project number. The project table has the project number and name. I am trying to get the person first and last name and the project name and number they worked on. I am really confused now.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to fix it in my post. But what if you post *your* SQL schema, instead of describing it in plain text?

Comment: I described my tables hopefully that can help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the 'table in the middle' in the query even though you do not return any values directly from that table:

```
SELECT f.FirstName, f.LastName, p.proNumber, p.proName
  FROM Field   AS f
  JOIN Work    AS w ON f.SSN = w.workSSN
  JOIN Project AS p ON p.proNumber = w.workProNumber
```

Also note that in the modern world, it is a very (*very*, **very**, ***very***) bad idea to use the SSN as primary key or foreign key column in a database.  You should use an ID column of some sort (EmployeeID).  If you must store the SSN, it should be encrypted, and access should be severely restricted to those with a need to know.  It can be a good idea to store the SNN in encrypted form in a separate table (with the corresponding EmployeeID as PK) with severely restricted access,